# Why is the end time of the logic of the Thread and the Task equal?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

I want to know the difference between a thread and a task.

In addition to the simple logic, the end times of two threads and two tasks were printed.
The end times of both tasks were the same.

I have a code.

When two threads are executed, the end time is the same as two tasks.

Because Tasks perform asynchronous parallelism, I thought the task's end time would be half of the Thread.

What is the error of my thoughts?

```
class Program
{
    static ConcurrentBag<string> cb = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sw.Start();

        // no.1 Thread  
        Thread1();
        Thread2();

        // no.2 Task
        //Task1();
        //Task2();

        while (true)
        {
            if (cb.Count == 1000000)
            {
                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine($"{cb.First()} Completed -> Time : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void CommonCode(string msg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            cb.Add(msg);
    }

    static void Thread1()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => {
            CommonCode("Thread");
        });
        t.Start();
    }

    static void Thread2()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => {
            CommonCode("Thread");
        });
        t.Start();
    }

    static async void Task1()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            CommonCode("Task");
        });
    }

    static async void Task2()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            CommonCode("Task");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "end times"? Can you explain exactly what is happening without having us executing the code and figuring out what you're referring to? Perhaps give some example outputs?

Comment: Also, can you explain more about why you expected tasks to perform better? In both cases you have two parallel execution threads filling up a concurrentbag, recording how long it takes for them to complete the filling, why did you expect tasks to perform better?

Comment: But... threads also do asynchronous parallelism. That's a major reason why we use threads in the first place. Really, what would you expect to work in any way different between the two specific approaches here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task` represents some piece of work that should be done. `Thread` is a unit of processing. Task **can** be executed on a thread. It depends on workload type.

There are two types of work: `1.` IO (network request, database query etc.) and `2.` CPU (any kind of computation). In the 1st case with proper `async/await` usage [there is no occupied thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). In the 2nd case - you still need a thread to do the work.

In your code you run `CommonCode` method in parallel using two threads and then using two tasks. `CommonCode` is a CPU bound workload, it's a synchronous code. So in both cases you still need a thread. No difference is expected here.

But with tasks it could be written more elegant:

```
Task.WhenAll(Task1(), Task2()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Thread t = new Thread();` create a completely new thread where as `Task.Run` will get a thread from a ThreadPool?

Comment: In your version the two Tasks run in parallel, but surely in the OP's code Task1 is awaited, so it must finish before Task2 is started?

Comment: @iakobski What do you mean? Using `Task.WhenAll` I created the task which will be completed when both `Task1()` and `Task2()` are completed.

Comment: @iakobski The OP doesn't await Task1 and Task2.

Comment: @iakobski Calling `Task1()` doesn't block further execution. Because there is no neither `await Task1()` nor `Task1().Result` (or `Task1().Wait()` or any similar).